# HTTPWebRequest GET error The remote server returned an error: (415) Unsupported Media Type

Tags: c#, json, rest, get, httpwebrequest

This code is supposed to give me JsonString in response.But I am getting an error

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (415) Unsupported Media Type.

```
string  Url = "https://abc.test.xyz.com/123456344589753/transactions";
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);
            string certThumbPrint = "ce03c469fb6c6dewwwww21886b7c1d405d954hshgd";
            X509Certificate2 cert = FindCertificateByThumbprint(certThumbPrint);
            if (cert != null)
            {
                request.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
            }
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.MediaType = "application/json";
            request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            string text;
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                text = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
```

Any suggestions to resolve this error

Answer (score 3):

From the [HTTP specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-22#section-6.5.13):

> **415 Unsupported Media Type**
>
> The 415 (Unsupported Media Type) status code indicates that the
> origin server is refusing to service the request because the payload
> is in a format not supported by the target resource for this method.
> The format problem might be due to the request's indicated Content-
> Type or Content-Encoding, or as a result of inspecting the data
> directly.

GET requests do not have payloads, so the server you're communicating with might not like that you're specifying a Content-Type in the request.

Comment: Exactly. And the solution is to set the `Accept` property: `request.Accept = "application/json";`